# gem install mechanize causing libxml errors(windows 7)

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Here is the cropped error when I tried the command '*gem install mechanize*'

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokog
iri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
 extconf.rb failed 
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

then I tried to install the libxml using '*gem install libxml*' and it returns following error

```
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: eimxml, eim_xml, irxml, libacl, libowl
```

It will be better if there is any EXE or precompiled installer that can install the mechanize with all the dependencies.

I am using Windows7(64 bit) and, ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: You need to follow the instructions at rubyinstaller.org *exactly*. Make sure to install the right version of ruby plus devkit, then try it again. If it doesn't work, fall back to 1.9.3, there's a good chance 2.0 isn't ready for the real world yet.

Comment: I have already installed a devkit[DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe] as per their sites instruction. may be you are right about the version. Basically I was having ruby with version 1.8.6; mechanize installation didn't work on that, so I have updated to the latest one. may be 1.9.3 can help as its a stable version.

Comment: try to install libv8 gem

Comment: libv8 gem installation says: "C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:58:in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but it is currently not available (RuntimeError)"